# SAS drive replacement in Proliant server and compatible drives

Tags: raid, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I am use an Prolian Server ML350-G5. The server has got two disk in RAID 1+0. The model of the disk is 432320-001 (146GB). One disk has shown an ambar light that means the disk needs to be replaced for another one.

The point is that when I ask for a new disk to offical HP reseller or to Amazon seller, they told me that the disks only has got 6 months of warranty. I consider too expensive one disk that has got only 6 months of warranty.

I ask here if I can take another way. The point is that I need to give more space to the server, but in my organization there is few people (5-10) using the application that are running in the server. The application is ContaPlus and FacturaPlus.

Is there a way to get compatible SAS more cheap the the original HP drive?

May I use SSD disks or other cheap way for do RAID10 in this server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your existing disk first. The 146GB 2.5" SAS disks are no longer manufactured. Even HP sends 300GB disks as replacements for 146GB drives.

You're in Spain, so your best bet is to buy [one or two replacement 146GB drives from eBay](http://www.ebay.es/sch/i.html?_odkw=146GB%20hp&_from=R40%7CR40&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313&_nkw=432320-001%20&_sacat=0). They're very inexpensive.

The server you're using, an HP ProLiant ML350 G5, is very old. I would not recommend using SSDs in it. If you use SATA SSDs in particular, they will link at 1.5Gbps instead of 3Gbps or 6Gbps. You'll lose a lot of throughput performance if you do so.

Comment: Thank you, but that hard disk are used, so do you bought disk in that conditions? For example, I see in Amazon that the disk new is really expensive (http://www.amazon.es/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=432320-001&rh=n%3A599370031%2Ck%3A432320-001). In other hand, when I see the hard disk in eeuu (new), I see prices too lower. When you can buy overthere a drive for 40$ new, here in Spain new, the disk costs around 210€.

Comment: The disks are not manufactured anymore. Buy used. Get an extra drive for insurance.

Comment: Sorry, but do you think that is reliable buy used drives? The point is that I need more space because I want concentrate all the things in this Proliant 350ML server. I think to buy 4 more used disk and then put them in RAID 1+0.

Comment: Sure. It's fine to use refurbished or used disks, as long as they're healthy.