# Compatible SATA disks for Proliant ML350 G5 server

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, sata

I have got a Proliant ML350 G5 server with two SAS drives of 146GB in RAID 1+0, but I would to add two SATA drives of 500GB in another RAID 1+0, but I don't know which are compatible. The measure of the SAS drives are 2.5', I suppose that the SATA must to be of 2.5' too, but where can I buy those disk as new?

Regards. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't buy SATA 2.5" disks. They're limited in capacity, and you'll find that SAS drives in the 2.5" form-factor are a better purchase.

Just look for used HP 2.5" SAS disks. They're available in: 72, 146, 300, 450, 600, 900 and 1200GB capacities, while SATA disks are pretty much 500GB and 1000GB. I'd recommend getting [600GB SAS disks from eBay](http://www.ebay.es/sch/i.html?_odkw=hp%20sas%202.5&_from=R40%7CR40%7CR40%7CR40&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313&_nkw=581311-001&_sacat=0), just like I recommended in your [other question](https://serverfault.com/a/671511/13325).

The other note about SATA on that era of server is that the speeds will be downshifted to 1.5Gbps per drive instead of 3Gbps or 6Gbps. SAS will negotiate to 3Gbps.

Comment: Thank you again. The point is I think that the company needs don't require much speed. Is an small business where 4 o 5 persons use the software of the server. I bought two 149GB SAS drive, but now I want more space for this server.